# Image inside tooltip tiptip

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, tiptip

I need to insert an image in a tooltip with hover effect.

```
$(".tel_view").tipTip({defaultPosition: "top", delay: 400, fadeIn: 400,keepAlive:true,activation:"click"});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="img_ag/lente.png" width="16" height="19" alt="lente"   class="tel_view" title="">
```

This is the image that i want insert to the tooltip.

```
<img src="img_ag/leg_in.png" id="prova">
```

Is possible insert an image into the tooltip? How it works?

Comment: Hey, just add your HTML to `title` attribute. It will work.

Comment: Hi, title="<img src='img_ag/leg_in.png'>" this is correct?

Comment: Yeah! I think that was the way.

Comment: mmmm look the syntax, this is my site http://www.lookcommunication.it/testalessio/. check the second line, first image. Thanks

Comment: Wait a minute, let me see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36384/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-reverter)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery UI has an alternative tool-tip widget that you might want to consider

here is a full example

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Custom content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .photo {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .photo .ui-widget-header {
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  .map {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
  }
  .ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 350px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "img, [data-geo], [title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
          var text = element.text();
          return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
            "' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
            "zoom=11&size=350x350&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&center=" +
            text + "'>";
        }
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "alt" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget photo">
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <h2>St. Stephen's Cathedral</h2>
    <h3><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=vienna,+austria&amp;z=11" data-geo="">Vienna, Austria</a></h3>
  </div>
  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wien_Stefansdom_DSC02656.JPG">
    <img src="images/st-stephens.jpg" alt="St. Stephen&apos;s Cathedral" class="ui-corner-all">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget photo">
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <h2>Tower Bridge</h2>
    <h3><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=london,+england&amp;z=11" data-geo="">London, England</a></h3>
  </div>
  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tower_bridge_London_Twilight_-_November_2006.jpg">
    <img src="images/tower-bridge.jpg" alt="Tower Bridge" class="ui-corner-all">
  </a>
</div>

<p>All images are part of <a href="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Wikimedia Commons</a>
and are licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en" title="Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0">CC BY-SA 3.0</a> by the copyright holder.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer pointed me to the jQuery UI tooltip widget, of which I was not aware. Nice, and quite powerful! To avoid confusion, you should edit the first line of this answer, from "Jquery got an amazing site" to "jQuery UI has an alternative tool-tip widget that you might want to consider."

Answer (score 2):

Hello You can set content in tipTip() like below :
For hover tipTip you have to remove `activation:"click"` parameter by default its displayed on hover. Please see this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/6qn1k506/2/)

```
$(".tel_view").tipTip({
    defaultPosition: "top", 
    delay: 400, 
    fadeIn: 400, 
    keepAlive: true, 
    content: '<img src="img_ag/leg_in.png" id="prova">'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, There are lot using different Jquery Plugin take a look at this demo
http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 1):

its just simple funny work is a solution of this problem. Problem is image loading So

```
        var ttfixer = "";
        $(".tooltipL").each(function(){    
            ttfixer += $(this).attr("title");
        });
        $("#tooltipimgfixer").html(ttfixer);
        $(".tooltipL").tipTip({ maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10 });
```

add Html

```
<div style="display:none" id="tooltipimgfixer"></div>
```

Now Image are loading in page load. Tooltip will work good,

Answer (score 1):

give solution gives us as a tooltip with hover effect you can use your .js and .css file also without .css and .js file you can't run this code.

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**HTML CODE LIKE**

```
<a id="riverroad" href="#" title="" >image of 1 Maple St.</a>
```

and **JAVASCRIPT CODE LIKE**

```
$( "#riverroad" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://www.codingscripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/jquery.png" />' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image html code as `title` attribute of the element on you set titTip.

Example code:

```
<span class='tel_view' title='<img src="img_ag/leg_in.png" id="prova">'></span>
```

The element can be an image o whatever you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/97qkE/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code like**

```
<div id="content"> </div>
```

**Java Script Code like**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#content").tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GSsrz5Mvj6I/Uac1p3R1kxI/AAAAAAAAA7k/QFNVmDW5k3U/s320/Tooltip.jpg" />' }); });
```