# How to display image in tooltip Bootstrap 4 with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

How to display image in tooltip Bootstrap 4

here is my code

```
         <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-info" title="<img src='{{ asset('images/desc/category.jpg') }}'  />"  data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{ asset('images/desc/category.jpg') }}" target="_blank" >
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
        </a>
```

But it dis play full path in tooltip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside tooltip tiptip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482578/image-inside-tooltip-tiptip)

Comment: i think you want a popover and not a tooltip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `data-html="true"`

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" class="btn btn-info" title="<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' />" >
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
```